# Etymology of "vestige"

Tags: etymology

The origin of *vestige* is said to be "from French, from Latin vestigium 'footprint'".

*vest-* means clothes, so does this prefix apply to *vestige* ?

Comment: No; *vestments* (clothing) derives from the Latin *vestimentum*. Moreover, M-W doesn't list *vest-* as a prefix.

Comment: Don't overplay the significant of *Latin **vestigium = footprint***. That's a "figurative" definition, not a literal one. The original Latin was probably just a general term meaning *mark, [remaining] trace*.

Comment: Indeed. There's one particularly juicy Latin rape scene where the husband returns home to find "another man's footprints in his bed" if you translate it too literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The etymologies of *vestigo* "to track" and *vestis* "clothing" are most probably not related, according to *Lewis & Short*:

> **vestis**, is, f. [Sanscr. root vas-, to put on; Gr. ἑσ-, fεσ-; cf. ἕννυμι, ἐσθής], *the covering for the body, clothes, clothing, attire, vesture*
>
> **ve-stīgo**, no perf. and sup., āre, 1, v. a. [etym. dub.; perh. Sanscr. vahis (bahis), out, and stigh-, to climb; cf. Gr. στίχος, a row, etc.; Angl. -Sax. stīgan; Germ. steigen, to climb].
> I. Prop., *to follow in the track of; to track, trace out*